# CruiseControl.net spaces in <cb:define> field splitting path

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, robocopy

I'm using the  field to define a path within CC.NET, but the path has spaces in it.
I use the definition within a robocopy task.  However when I run the robocopy command in cruisecontrol.net, the path C:\my projects is being interpreted as C:\my.

How can I get around this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using preprocessor text constants it should be something like this:

```
<cb:define path="&quot;C:\my projects&quot;" />
```

As an alternative you could use quotation when you pass your preprocessor constant to the Robocopy task:

```
<cb:define path="C:\my projects" />
<!-- ... -->
<sourcecontrol type="robocopy">
  <repositoryRoot>"$(path)"</repositoryRoot>
</sourcecontrol>
```